# How to set a default attribute to all elements

Tags: html

For example, I have the following code

```
<form>
  <input type="text" required="true">
  <input type="text" required="true">
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Guys, is it possible to set a default value "true" to the attribute "required"?
Something like this:

```
<form required="true">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You just did? I think `required="true"` is pretty much all that's needed to set a default value like that.

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could [use JavaScript](https://optinmonster.com/docs/how-to-make-your-fields-required-with-custom-html/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The required option on input is removable by the user easily by inspecting the source code.

I think the best way to do that is to check all input with a javascript function call before sending the data like it's explain in the example bellow.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

> Edit :

```
<form id="yourFormId">
   ..
</form>
```

And if you want you can use JQuery, just do :

```
$('#yourFormId').submit(function() {
    // Something
    return true; // True submit your form.
    //return false; // False cancel your form.
});
```

Comment: But `return false;` doesn't prevent a form submission.

Comment: Yes it does. Did you try the example ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with pure HTML. Some templating languages may have this feature (or something similar).

You could consider using javascript.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].required = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it it possible in HTML but you can do with the help of jquery like this :
HTML code:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(function(){
       $("input").prop('required',true);
});
```

check : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/13nfxsn1/7/)

Answer (score 0):

nope. unless you catch the form submit event in javascript and disable it if any field is unfilled or with javascript add the required attribute like what https://stackoverflow.com/users/7183244/keegan-teetaert suggested, otherwise it's easier just to write required for every field. I don't see the pain in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `html` or `css`, you should use `javascript`, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").forEach(function(e) { 
    e.setAttribute("required", true);  
});
```

The selector selects all inputs of text type.
Use this code after document has been loaded

Comment: just change the line `e.attributes.required = true;`  by `e.setAttribute("required", true);`. I've updated the answer and the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/13nfxsn1/17/